# Magento2: How can customize fulltext to like in admin product grid search?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I want to customize fulltext search with like in product admin grid in Magento2.3. Please find below screenshot:
[image]

I have checked Module-catalog search for admin grid but unable to do customization.
Anyone have an idea for that, How can do this?